# How to stop text going past footer?

Tags: css, html, web

If I put a lot of text in my  element, the text flows past my footer. How can I make my footer stay at the bottom regardless if there is a lot of text or no text.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practice_1.css"
        media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Orbitron|Open Sans">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="siteName">
                    <h1>Website Name</h1>
                </div class="siteName"> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">View Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <section>
            <article>
                <p>
                </p>
            </article>
        </section>

        <footer>    
            <small>&copy; 2014 Name. All rights reserved.</small>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
* {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
border : none;
}

body {
font-family : 'Open Sans', serif;
background-color : #FFFFFF;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.siteName {
float: left;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-left: 300px;
font-size: 1.4em;
font-family: Orbitron;
font-weight: 700;
}

nav {
background-color : #212121;
text-align : right;
}

nav ul li {
display : inline-block;
list-style-type : none;
transition: all 0.2s;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
color : #FFFFFF;
display : block;
line-height : 40px;
padding : 0 25px;
text-decoration : none;
font-size : .95em;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: Lato;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
color : #666;
}

section {
margin-top : 50px;
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
width: 80%;
}

footer {
text-align : center;
background-color : #212121;
color: #FFFFFF;
height: 150px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier, this is what happens when I add too much text.

[IMGUR link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvlAA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the question again and you are looking for sticky footer.

[Find it here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

Here is a demo of the sticky footer working with your code (I'm sure you can tidy it up a little).

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/C3j7m/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="siteName">
                 <h1>Website Name</h1>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">View Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="main">
        <section>
            <article>
                <p>ddddd</p>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <small>&copy; 2014 Name. All rights reserved.</small>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    border : none;
}
body {
    font-family :'Open Sans', serif;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.siteName {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 300px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: Orbitron;
    font-weight: 700;
}
nav {
    background-color : #212121;
    text-align : right;
}
nav ul li {
    display : inline-block;
    list-style-type : none;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
    color : #FFFFFF;
    display : block;
    line-height : 40px;
    padding : 0 25px;
    text-decoration : none;
    font-size : .95em;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: Lato;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a {
    color : #666;
}
section {
    margin-top : 50px;
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    width: 80%;
}
footer {
    text-align : center;
    background-color : #212121;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
}
/* must be same height as the footer */
 footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px;
    /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
}
/*Opera Fix*/
 body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;
}
```

---

If you just want it under the content of the page then:

Take off `position: absolute` from the footer.

**CSS:**

```
footer {
    text-align : center;
    background-color : #212121;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/C3j7m/1/)

Comment: This worked! Thanks for taking the time to help out.

Comment: @user3788908 Not a problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the footer in a `<div>`. set your desired width and height. Also set style overflow:hidden. Play around with that a little and choose the `<div>` styles that suit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to `footer`

```
position: fixed;
```

and to `section`

```
padding-bottom: 150px;
```

I tested it and it works.

Comment: The `padding-bottom: 150px;` prevents your footer from hiding part of the text.

Comment: And this is assuming that you want a sticky footer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure understand your problem clearly. If you want to fix the height 150 and if the text goes more than that also you want to display the content means you have two ways.

**Solution 1:** You can add scrollbar so that if it extends a scroll will display. Use footer CSS like below.

```
   footer {
   text-align : center;
   background-color : #212121;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   height: 150px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   overflow:auto;
   width: 100%;
   }
```

**Solution 2:** You can set the min height instead of height inr footer. If it extends it will extend automatically. Use footer CSS like below.

```
   footer {
   text-align : center;
   background-color : #212121;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   min-height: 150px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   }
```